# What are some of the math departments in US and Canada that has good research programs in Number Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hi all,

I am currently a master student of mathematics in Turkey and I want to do PhD, preferably in either algebraic number theory or combinatorial number theory. I am thinking of applying to grad schools in US or Canada. Which departments that have research programs in these areas(aside from the ones in top 20 or so) can you suggest me to apply in the next fall? Thanks!

Comment: This is just a general comment: I heard about an international student who knew very little about US universities and decided to go to a school that was very prestigious in general but didn't have much of a math department. It makes me wonder whether there should be some sort of guide to math schools in the US.

Comment: Well if you just want a rough sense of which mathematics programs are well regarded USNWR is ok (http://grad-schools.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/number-theory-rankings).  I wouldn't put too much stock in the difference between 30 and 40 on that list, but it will help you catch, for example, schools that are well regarded in general, but with a less prestigious math program.

Comment: @tarikd, you may find GH's suggestions(may not be complete) about Number theory grad programs in the US in the comment section under his answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89270/roadmap-to-understand-the-statement-and-current-status-of-the-most-general-state/89301#89301

But I bet that the best way is to look at the math webpages of the first 100 or so ranking universities by yourself and choose those that fit your interests. Then narrow down to a handful of them. 

Comment: Of course that does not really matter, but I'd rather see this question been closed as "subjective and argumentative". The pre-fixed set of reasons to close a question is clumsy enough, not to use the right reason when there is an obvious one :-) 

Comment: There's a pretty good correlation between the overall quality of a department and the quality of any given area. So another reasonable method is to get a list of the better departments over all (e.g. search for "National Research Council rankings in mathematics") and then find the departments that have a strong presence in the areas you care about. You might also inquire about how many PhDs they've given out recently in your area and what positions their graduates have gotten.